# How can i retrive all value seperated by comma in sentense from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code in which i have one text area which take inputs as separate value and combine it in a sentence. For example if user enter andheri bandra dadar then and store in $data then it display as andheri,bandra,dadar. Also text area is autocompleted means if you enter 'da' then it will auto fill with dadar

I tried following function then it search all values in sentence but it only first value from sentence i.e andheri. Please help me.

```
//code
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM broker_property WHERE find_in_set(area,'$data')") or die(mysql_error())
```

Here `area` is a column in mysql table and `$data` is sentense containg all sub value seperated with commas.

Comment: hey i got solution...i replace find_in_set(area,'$data')") with find_in_set(area,'".$data."')") and it works fine...thank you bro for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `MySQL CONCAT_WS OR CONCAT` clause that will help you to join string.

**Official Document** : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

**Example**

```
select * from broker_property where concat_ws(' ',area,$data) like 'CONDITIONS';
```

or you can also use equality check in where clause.

Comment: hey i got solution...i replace find_in_set(area,'$data')") with find_in_set(area,'".$data."')") and it works fine...thank you bro for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each of your words in quotes and then use this

```
SELECT * FROM broker_property WHERE area IN ($data)
```

Example

```
 SELECT * FROM broker_property WHERE area IN ("First","Second","Third")
```

Comment: yeah it is right but i dont know how many values user will enter in text area?? I have to retrive those value which user wiill enter. It is dynamic.

Comment: This should work for any number of values. Provided you generate your string like this `"word1","word2","word3"` and so on

Comment: yeah but i have more then 400 values. So i can put all 400 value right??

Comment: Yes you can put. Just that `IN` is not a very fast way to search for something, but I guess in this scenario there won't be many alternates

Comment: yeah also i have to put 400 values in IN clause which is not good programming

Comment: That's a whole lot different topic :) `IN` is one of the answers to your question, not the Only answer.

Comment: hey i got solution...i replace find_in_set(area,'$data')") with find_in_set(area,'".$data."')") and it works fine...thank you bro for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM broker_property WHERE area IN ('$data')");
```

Comment: hey i got solution...i replace find_in_set(area,'$data')") with find_in_set(area,'".$data."')") and it works fine...thank you bro for your reply